# How to access javascript prototype method via jquery listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, prototype

I have simple javascript "class" with prototype methods, but in method `itemDelete()` I got error message `this.save is not a function`. I think is because of jquery listener, but I do not know how to solve this.

```
function Manager(el, type) {
  this.el = el;
  this.type = type;

  this.render();
}

Manager.prototype.render = function() {
  // render stuff
};

Manager.prototype.itemAdd = function(item) {
  var element = $('#' + this.el).html(item);

  element.on('click', this.itemDelete);
}

Manager.prototype.itemDelete = function(event) {
  $('#' + event.target).remove();
  this.save('itemDelete');
}

Manager.prototype.save = function(method) {
  // save stuff
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `itemDelete`? Like `Manager.prototype.itemDelete()` or `new Manager().itemDelete()`

Comment: @adiga - It's in the question: `element.on('click', this.itemDelete);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, I missed that part.